# Rewrite rule stripping characters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have this rewrite rule in my .htaccess file, but in PHP when I get the url ($_GET['url']) it strips out one of the slashes from http://

```
RewriteRule ^details/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ details/index.php?urlid=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

If the url is http://foo.com/details/12345/http://www.bar.com/dsfkjds, PHP sees http:/www.bar.com/dsfkjds

I'm not sure if this is a PHP, regex or apache problem. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: just do a `str_replace('http:/', 'http://', $_GET['url'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Apache normalizing the path segments. It's too late for the RewriteRule to detect or change it.

You can however see the original request URL in [`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`](http://www.google.com/search?q=%24_SERVER%5B%22REQUEST_URI%22%5D) and apply your regex again to see the full parameter.

```
preg_match("#^/+details/+([0-9]+)/+(.*)$#", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $m)
and $url = $m[2];
```